# Is there any ROS drivers for FLIR A65/35 Camera?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have FLIR A65 and A35 camera and i would like to download ROS drivers for those camera.

here's a link to the website if you don't know what flir A65 or  A35

[CLICK HERE](http://www.flir.com/automation/display/?id=56341)

[image: image description]

**THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219743/is-there-any-ros-drivers-for-flir-a65/35-camera-?/) by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-10-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-23**:
And what have you found yourself? A quick google leads me to [flir_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/flir_driver) (src: [tum-ros-pkg/code/drivers/flir_driver/](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/tum-ros-pkg/code/drivers/flir_driver/), which is old, but may be a starting point.

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-10-23**:
great, but how can we run it as ROS package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We successfully used the [flir_gige](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/flir_gige) driver with a A35 camera, so I'd recommend to try that one.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-10-30**:
after you downloaded  the driver to laptop, can you please explain to me how did you run this package by typing some commands in the terminal

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-10-30**:
It's a standard catkin package and gets built like all other ROS packages. The launch files are largely self explanatory. I unfortunately don't have the time to provide detailed instructions.

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-11-05**:
@Stefan kohlbrecher   Please if you have the time do so ....Thank you for your time